# How to change ownership of a binary generated through Bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

Suppose I have a binary that is generated from the following rule:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "script",
  srcs = ["script.c"],
)
```

I am then using this binary in my tests:

```
cc_test(
  name = "test",
  srcs = ["test.cc"],
  data = [":script"],
)
```

My question is: Is it possible to change the ownership (`chown root:root`) and permissions (`chmod +s`) of this binary through *bazel itself*?

The binary contains some commands that can only be executed by root, hence the need to change ownership and permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Bazel tests are run in a sandbox. The details depend on your operating system, what flags you're passing to bazel, and which bazel version. [`tags = ["requires-fakeroot"]`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common.tags) (on your `cc_test`) is the way to ask a sandbox implementation to run a test as root. As the documentation says `This is only supported on Linux.` though.

That tag results in the test being run as root within its [namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html). That means it can do many things root can (create suid root files, mount things, configure network devices, etc), but nothing with effects outside of the namespace (so it can't shut down your computer for example).

The permissions you mentioned would make the file [setuid root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). Normal users can't do that because then you could just make a copy of bash suid root, run it, and become root. That means you'll need to run your build as root if it's going to produce a setuid root file, which is not the usual way to run bazel. If you're just looking to create setuid root files on your target system, I would package the files in a tarball with [pkg_tar](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/blob/main/pkg/docs/reference.md#pkg_tar) and use `mode = "6555"` to make it suid. The default owner is `0.0`, aka root, already.